# How do you forget a WiFi connection?

Tags: wifi, networking, odin

Basically I have a wifi connection set, that I want to remove/erase connection details/credentials. In Gnome settings you have option *Forget network*. I couldn't find anything similar in eOS.

Also, you can not edit connection settings unless you have connected to the WiFi, that does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

How very, very odd. I, too, cannot delete a wireless network from the list with any pointer or keyboard combinations. That said, because Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, you can do this "the hard way" through the command line:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Switch to the superuser (as you'll need to go into a protected directory)

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
2. Navigate to the `system-connections` directory for Network Manager:

   ```
   cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
   ```
3. Remove the `.nmconnection` records you no longer want

Hopefully this is something that gets resolved with a future update.

Comment: Thanks. I know the power of terminal, but that's not the point. There should be simple GUI option. Filed a feature request [https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-network/issues/327](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-network/issues/327)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing. The answer is merely a means to accomplish the immediate goal 

Comment: It is strange that this hasn't been accepted as the correct answer. Thx @matigo